# Check/Uncheck all checkboxes using bindings instead of a loop?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I have a bunch of `checkboxes` in a `grid`. I have two `buttons`, a 'check all' button and a 'uncheck all' button. The names speak for themselves, but when I click the 'check all' button, all the checkboxes should be checked. When I click the 'uncheck all' button, all the checkboxes should be unchecked.

Now, I can make a command to loop through each checkbox and check/uncheck them for the buttons, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way using some binding. For instance, I tried this:

In the xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="2"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="2"
              Grid.Column="2"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
</Grid>
```

In my view model:

```
private bool _isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return _isChecked; }
    set { _isChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); }
}
```

The above doesn't work though, since ALL the checkboxes are bound to the same bool. So checking/unchecking one does the the same to all of them. But I'd like to do something like that. Is there something I'm not thinking of, or is the main way to just loop through them all?

Comment: Consider rewording the title, when I read the `without a loop` part I initially thought `Bad question, of course you need a loop!`. But with an example of what you tried it is actually a good question.

Comment: there are different ways to do what you want without iteration but i'm not going to tell you - it would uncessairily obfuscate what you are trying to do. no need to turn toggling checkboxes into an overcomplicated mess

Comment: I'm with @Dbl. Why overcomplicate something that a simple loop can solve?

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I guess I'll use a loop. Wasn't sure if there was something I was missing. Would putting this loop in the xaml.cs for the window be breaking the MVVM pattern? I assume not since it's just dealing with the view.

Comment: It would be a violation. You are supposed to use commands in a hosting view model to run view model manipulation. You should look into more tutorials still if you think codebehind is necessary. For almost every case there is a rather simple view model+binding based solution to your problems

Comment: "Would putting this loop in the xaml.cs for the window be breaking the MVVM pattern?". Yes. You should iterate through the items in the source collection and set the IsChecked property of your data objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewModel approach is working fine

```
private bool _isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return _isChecked; }
    set { _isChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); }
}
```

The point is that you have to define a binding to an `ItemsSource` also (that is the equivalent of the loop) and a Collection of objects having such `IsChecked` property. In this way each checkbox will be enabled and disabled independently

Comment: Is there a chance you could show a small example of this? My main concern is the layout. The checkboxes are in a grid right now, 9 of them total in a 3x3 layout fashion. If I use an ItemsSource, how would I line them up properly? Could I just put an 'int' property on the objects and then bind the grid.row / column to that? (No example needed if this is possible).

Comment: Just tested it, I can :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something I'm not thinking of, or is the main way to just loop through them all?

No and Yes. You should use a loop to iterate all items in the source collection and set their *respective* IsChecked property to true.

Obviously you cannot bind all CheckBoxes to a single source property and simply set this one if you want to be able to check and uncheck each CheckBox individually.

There is no other or better way to do this than using some kind of loop.